# What does the word 'there' mean?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

In this following context, what does the word 'there' mean?
Is it 'existential there'?
Should I take its actual sentence as: people who ...are found?

Context:

> There are found people who are short-lived, and those that are
> long-lived; there are found people who are very sick, and those that
> are healthy; there are found people who are hideous, and those that
> are beautiful;

Comment: The word ***found*** is syntactically superfluous, so you should parse the text as if it wasn't there anyway. It just adds a little "emphasis" - a bit like saying *There **[do] exist** people like that* instead of *There **are** such people*.

Comment: Remember to link to the source [Collected Wheel Publications Volume XXVI](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Collected_Wheel_Publications_Volume_XXVI/Dgc4BgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22there+are+found+people+who+are+hideous,+and+those+that+are+beautiful%3B%22&pg=PA24&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: And note this is a translation of a saying from scripture, probably the 1926 Pali text society translation, So you may expect odd grammar (as a result of the age and the translations)

Answer (score 1):

This construction is mildly literary or poetic, because it involves an inversion.

The unpacked, extremely cumbersome structure would be this passive one:

> There are people who [are] found who are short-lived,...

This reveals that it's the usual "there" of "there are".

Note that the second [are] is ambiguous in tense due to the ellipsis. It could just as easily be rendered [can be], [have been], etc.

As FumbleFingers wrote, the meaning is the same as "There are people who..." except for the change in [evidentiality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidentiality), which in this case seems to only be included for style anyway.

Comment: ''people are seen to be short-lived and longlived, sickly and     healthy, ugly an beautiful,...'' this is translation of original Text.

Comment: @SakyaKim That wouldn't be exactly equivalent. A closer version would be "There are short-lived people and long-lived people, sickly people and healthy people, ugly people and beautiful people." The version you gave could be interpreted as the same people being both short- and long-lived, sickly and healthy, ugly and beautiful, which is not the intended meaning :)

Comment: yes. This translation is not as the original Text, it is only interpretation. @Luke Sawczak.

Comment: but the Text (pali word) gave passive voice as: people who are short-lived are seen(/found/seemed/appeared); people who are long-lived are seen;..

Comment: @SakyaKim Ah, interesting. That's probably why the translator insisted on using 'found' here when it's not necessary to the English meaning. If that's the phrasing and it's natural in Pali, I would say the translation in the original question is a good one, even if it's a little hard to parse. In English 'people are seen to be short-lived' does not mean the same as 'people who are short-lived are seen'.

Comment: The Swedish for "there is/are" is "det finns", literally, "it is found".

Comment: @ColinFine Indeed, the suitability of the translation does depend somewhat on whether there was any way to say it in Pali without seen/found or whether that is the only (natural) way to predicate existence...

Comment: yes. I found some translator did the same Text as: 'people are seen to be short-lived'. @Luke Sawczak

Comment: For, good Gotama, human beings of short life-span are to be seen and those of long life-span; those of many and those of few illnesses; those who are ugly, those who are beautiful; those who are of little account, (PTS version: The Collection of The Middle Length Sayings (Majjhima Nikāya), Vol. 3 by I.B.Horner)

Comment: @SakyaKim This again is different. First, 'are to be seen' is more or less equivalent to 'exist': they are there if you look for them. Second, notice the repetition of 'and those': the translator is careful to ensure that it's not the *same* people who are ugly and beautiful, etc.