# What is different between 'there are found' and 'are to be seen'?

Tags: sentence-construction, usage

There are two translated versions from the same source:

1.

> For, good Gotama, human beings of short life-span **are to be seen** and
> those of long life-span; those of many and those of few illnesses;
> those who are ugly, those who are beautiful; ... . Now what, good
> Gotama, is the cause, what the reason that lowness and excellence are
> to be seen among human beings while they are in human form?"

2. 

> **There are found** people who are short-lived, and those that are
> long-lived; there are found people who are very sick, and those that
> are healthy; there are found people who are hideous, and those that
> are beautiful; ... . What then, Master Gotama, is the reason that
> among human beings such inferiority and superiority are found?

Here, what I want to know is whether the translations– 'be to be seen' in 1st version; 'there are found' in 2nd one– are the same meanings or not.

Sentence sources:

1. [The Collection of The Middle Length Sayings (Majjhima Nikāya), Vol.3](https://www.tititudorancea.com/z/collection_middle_length_sayings_majjhima_nikaya_3_ib_horner.htm#page/280/mode/2up)
2. [Collected Wheel Publications Vol XXVI](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Collected_Wheel_Publications_Volume_XXVI/Dgc4BgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Thus+kamma+divides+beings+into+the+high+and+low.%22&pg=PA24&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: [The Swedish for "there is/are" is "det finns", literally, "it is found".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/333736/what-does-the-word-there-mean#comment632980_333742) Which observation quite possibly "explains" both of these questions.

Answer (score 0):

No, in detail "to be seen" and "there are found" aren't exactly the same meaning. One is about "seeing" and one is about "finding".

But in the general sense, the two translations convey the same general idea, which could be expressed in many different ways. The speaker asserts the existence of people who are fortunate and those who are unfortunate and challenges the Buddha to justify this inequality.